# split div in two rows like multi column CSS property

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

Is there any solution to split content of a div automatically in multi rows? (like when we using `multi column CSS properties` to split a div in multi columns)

Comment: Not that i'm aware of - why don't you just nest two div.row within the main div?

Comment: Because the content of my div isn't static. I want to split the content in multi rows automatically. Is there any solution by using just `css`?

Comment: No. I'd recommend to inject the dynamic content into two divs(which will be the rows).